# jQuery SetTimeout for Show / Hide div does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, show-hide

I am writing a jQuery which is supposed show/hide a series of images after an image is clicked. It basically, hides the current image and shows the next one when `onClick` event.

The function I have written so far works except one feature: On image 3, I want to set a timer and then switch to image 4, even if the user hasn't click it.

I am using a `setTimeout` and the timeout triggers except that it does not switch to next image.

This is my function:

```
(function($) { 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0;
        $('.squirrel').click(function () {          
            $(this).hide();
            var next = $(this).next();
            if (next.length == 0){
                next = $(this).parent().find('.squirrel').first();
                count = -1;
            }            
            next.show();            
            if (count == 1) {
                setTimeout(
                    function() {
                        alert("Should switch to 4 now but it doesn't work");                            
                        $(this).hide();
                        var next = $(this).next();          
                        next.show();
              
                        count++;
                    }, 2000
                );
            } else {            
                count++;            
            }       
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="squirrelContainer">
    <img src="1.png" class="squirrel default">
    <img src="2.png" class="squirrel">
    <img src="3.png" class="squirrel" id = "3">
    <img src="4.png" class="squirrel">
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pazzesco/jundzs0b/10/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the same image not the next one.

```
(function($) { 
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
$('.squirrel').click(function ()
{
    $(this).hide();
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (next.length == 0)
    {
        next = $(this).parent().find('.squirrel').first();
        count = -1;
    }            
    next.show();
        
    if (count == 1) 
    {
        let that = $(this).next();
        setTimeout(
        function() 
        {
             console.log("Should switch to 4 now but it doesn't work");
                        
            that.hide();
            var next = that.next();          
            next.show();
            count++;
        }, 2000
        );
    } 
    else 
    {
        count++;
    }
});
});
})(jQuery);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dyt9opLz/

Comment: Thank you, man! I knew I was missing something similar.